# rxjs 5.2: ReplaySubject wait for 3 seconds and throw timeout if only empty

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I have setter and getter in my Angular service like below, what I want is if the `vizItemStream$` is not in 3 seconds, I want to throw timeout error. If item is set or already set then It shouldn't throw (if non-empty).

```
vizItemStream$ = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);

set visualizeItem(item: VizItem) {
    this.vizItemStream$.next(item);
}

get visualizeItem$(): Observable<VizItem> {
    //Only throw timeout if there are no items emitted in 3 seconds
    // this.vizItemStream$.timeout(3000);
    let sub = Observable.empty().delay(3000).subscribe(e => {
        this.vizItemStream$.isEmpty().subscribe(e => {
            this.vizItemStream$.error(new Error('Timeout'));    
        });
        sub.unsubscribe();
    });        
    return this.vizItemStream$.asObservable();
}
```

I tried different options but none I could make it work. Any help how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`race`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.6/src/operators/race.ts#L13-L20) operator and a [`timer`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-timer) to get the behaviour you are looking for:

```ts
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/concatMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/race';

get visualizeItem$(): Observable<VizItem> {
  return this.vizItemStream$
    .race(Observable
      .timer(3000)
      .concatMap(() => Observable.throw(new Error('Timeout'))))
    .asObservable();
}
```

The `race` operator:

> Returns an Observable that mirrors the first source Observable to emit an item from the combination of this Observable and supplied Observables.

Comment: This is working fine but the ```subscription ``` success function also getting called. Like ```this.srs.visualizeItem$
            .pipe(concatMap((d: VizItem) => {                
                this.itemAnalyzing = d.item;
                console.log('With in sub')            
                if (!d || !d.item) {
                    return this.router.navigate([/queries/ig.test(url) ? '/queries' : /threats/ig.test(url) ? '/threats' : '/investigations']);
                }```

Comment: And also the error function ```)).subscribe(r => {}, err => {
                //this.notification.error('ERROR', 'Something went wrong, please see console');
                console.log(err);
                this.loading.next(false);
                return this.router.navigate([/queries/ig.test(url) ? '/queries' : /threats/ig.test(url) ? '/threats' : '/investigations']);
            });```

Comment: Using the `race` operator like this will see either one or more values emitted within 3 seconds or it will see an error emitted. If you believe you are seeing something different there is either a bug with `race` (highly unlikely) or there is more going on (e.g. multiple subscriptions) that's not apparent from the limited (and hard to read) context of your comments. I'd suggest incorporating `race` into your code and asking another question with sufficient context.

Comment: The problem was with the answer's use of `concat` instead of `concatMap`. Using `concat` saw the timer's value emitted before the error.